# How to support multiple domain name for the same project in Visual Studio 2019 and asp.net core app?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I have a project that is written on the top of Asp.NET 5/Core using Visual Studio 2019.

My project has multi-tenancy support and need to be able to map multiple local domains to the project to test out multi-tenancy.

How can I bind a second local domain to point to the same running host? I added `tenant1.website` and `tenant2.website` in the `.hosts` file like so

```
127.0.0.1     tenant1.website
127.0.0.1     tenant2.website
```

I tried to modify the `.vs\PrjectName\config\applicationhost.config` and added new binding like this

```
 <site name="ProjectName.Web" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="ProjectName.Web AppPool">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\ProjectName\ProjectName.Web" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:37893:localhost" />
          <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44356:localhost" />

          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:37893:tenant1.website" />
          <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44356:tenant1.website" />

          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:37893:tenant2.website" />
          <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44356:tenant2.website" />

        </bindings>
 </site>
```

But, when I go to `https://tenant1.website:44356` I get the following error

> This site can’t be reached

How can I correctly bind `tenant1.website` and `tenant2.website` to my locally running app using IIS Express?

Comment: When you go to `https://tenant1.website`, do you use port 44356 as specified in your bindings?  e.g. `https://tenant1.website:44356`

Comment: @PaulSuart yes I get this `tenant1.website` can't be found

Comment: We have a similar set-up.  The only other thing we do that you're possibly not doing is to set the `Project Url` on the "Web" tab of the web project's properties (right click web project > Properties).

Comment: Checked my local setup for this - I use `tenant1.localhost` not `tenant1.website` - could be part of it too.

Comment: I can't find the where to set the `Project URL` from inside the properties. This is an asp.net core app not asp.net mvc. I'll try to change the host

Comment: Is `launchSettings.json` still a thing for asp.net core sites?

Comment: it sounds like it but not sure how to really get it working https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I saw that too. Sorry I can't help more.